# Too few arguments to constructor using ConfigFactoryInterface

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to use ConfigFactoryInterface in a class constructor function this way:

> use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
>
> class MyClass {
>
> /**   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface   */
>
> protected $config;
>
> /**   * @param \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface
>   $config_factory   */
>
> public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory)
>   {   $this->config = $config_factory;   }
>
> ...

Drupal is throwing an Argument Count Error: Too few arguments to function ( 0 passed and exactly 1 expected).

I'm using Drupal version 8.5.6

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. When you create an instance of your class, you need to send it something that implements ConfigFactoryInterface. But without knowing more if what you are trying to achieve, it is hard to help you.

Comment: If you are trying to create config entities, read [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/creating-a-configuration-entity-type-in-drupal-8)

Comment: If you are trying to create your own service, and inject / read from the config, you will needs a mymodule.services.yml file,  [see this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241852/dependency-inject-a-class-with-values-from-a-config-object)

Comment: @2pha I had this file of course, I just had something wrong defined in it

Comment: @2pha That was great! Thanks for the tip!